# In Firefox only, my twitter typeahead search input is clearing out when I click anywhere

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, twitter-typeahead

Issue:
  In Firefox only, after I enter an value into a typeahead input, the value sets correctly.  When I click anywhere else on my screen (including outside of the Firefox window), that value clears.  Even when I alt-tab away from the window, the value is reset.

It should be noted that I am using knockout as well.

Here is my html:

```
<input placeholder="Search for a lodge..." data-bind="typeahead: selectedLodgeID, value: selectedLodgeText, suggestions: lodgeList, suggestionsText: 'Name', suggestionsValue: 'ID'" />
```

Here is my typeahead js:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['typeahead'] = {
'after': ['options', 'foreach'],
'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

    var textBinding = allBindings.get('value') || false;
    if (!textBinding)
        throw new Error("typeahead binding must include a value binding.");

    var suggestions = allBindings.get('suggestions') || false;
    if (!suggestions)
        throw new Error("typeahead binding must include a suggestions observableArray.");

    var suggestionsText = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('suggestionsText')) || false;
    if (!suggestionsText)
        throw new Error("typeahead binding must include a suggestionsText string.");

    var suggestionsValue = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('suggestionsValue')) || false;
    if (!suggestionsValue)
        throw new Error("typeahead binding must include a suggestionsValue string.");

    var valueAllowUnset = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('valueAllowUnset')) || false;

    var substringMatcher = function () {
        return function findMatches(query, callback) {
            var matches = [];
            var filter = new RegExp(query, 'i');
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(suggestions(), function (item) {
                var text = item[suggestionsText];
                var id = item[suggestionsValue];
                if (filter.test(text)) {
                    matches.push({ value: text.trim(), id: id });
                }
            });
            callback(matches);
        };
    };

    $(element).typeahead({ hint: true, highlight: true, minLength: 1, limit: 5 }, { source: substringMatcher() });
    $(element).on("change", function () {
        if (!valueAllowUnset) {
            value(null);
            textBinding(null);
        }
    });

    value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue === null && !valueAllowUnset) {
            $(element).typeahead('val', '');
        }
    });

    $(element).on('typeahead:selected  typeahead:autocompleted', function (eventArgs, selected) {
        if (typeof selected === 'object') {
            value(selected.id);
            textBinding(selected.value);
        } else {
            value(null);
            textBinding(null);
        }
    });
}
};
ko.expressionRewriting.twoWayBindings['typeahead'] = true;
```

here is the additional relevant js:

```
window.DashboardViewModel = function (startupLodge) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedLodgeID = ko.observable();
    self.selectedLodgeText = ko.observable();

    self.selectedLodgeID.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            SetLodgeText(newValue);  
    });
    var SetLodgeText = function (lodgeID) {
        for (var index = 0; index < self.lodgeList().length; ++index) {
            var lodge = self.lodgeList()[index];
            if (lodge.ID == lodgeID) {
                self.selectedLodgeText(lodge.Name);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

As I mentioned before, I can not reproduce this in Chrome or in IE, only in Firefox.  If i put a breakpoint at the start of selectedLodgeID.subscribe(), it will hit multiple times, although this is because when I click "Continue" after the first breakpoint it is the equivalent of clicking anywhere, which as mentioned before causes the input to clear out.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you doing `valueAllowUnset`? You have a change trigger that clears value unless `valueAllowUnset`. Change typically fires on blur, which happens when you click outside the element.

Comment: @RoyJ Figured it out-- In Chrome and In IE changing the value of my input (to display the text value) does not fire an on-change event, however, in Firefox change that value through jquery does result in the onchange event being fired.

Comment: Since you've got a `value` binding on the element, you shouldn't need to use jQuery to change the value, just change the observable. Once you have a viewmodel entry to control a DOM element, even in a binding handler, use the viewmodel.

Comment: @RoyJ I misspoke.  When I said "through jquery" I meant "through my view model".  Anyway, seems like this problem is mostly solved.

Comment: @USER_8675309 Did the answer provided work for you?

Comment: @NathanHall The answer does not work for me -- I worked around a different solution that can handle all my typeahead inputs.  the reason the `'keyup'` listener will not work here is because if i type in an "a", the kockout foreach binding will try to match this to one from the list of possible selections, and upon failing to do so will clear the "a" out of the input

Answer (score 0):

Try `valueUpdate : 'keyup'` to update your view model as soon as the user releases the enter key.

```
<input placeholder="Search for a lodge..." data-bind="typeahead: selectedLodgeID, value: selectedLodgeText, valueUpdate : 'keyup', suggestions: lodgeList, suggestionsText: 'Name', suggestionsValue: 'ID'" />
```